# QTextEdit MacOS render performance

Tags: qt, opengl, qtextedit

I've discovered very strange behaviour of QTextEdit render performance when building on Mac OS (Qt 5.9.1). When I have another qgraphicsview with QGLWidget viewport (sometimes it is hidden or closed, so I guess first setting QGLWidget as somebody's viewport is the event for performance failure), the QTextEdit starts working slow, with tracing to some CoreGraphics image manipulations with alpha.
I made an experiments, when graphicsview and qtextedit has QGLWidget/QWidget and got following results: (QGraphicsView viewport / QTextEdit viewport / QTextedit performance)

1. QGLWidget / QGLWidget / slow
2. QWidget / QWidget / fast
3. QGLWidget / QWidget very slow
4. QWidget / QGLWidget / slow

So, why using QGLWidget in some other widget causes QTextEdit performance to fail?

Answer (score 0):

Switching to QOpenGLWidget did the trick.